Reconnecting to Dbus daemon after a failover from an application written in vala
I have an application written in vala which communicates to another process (written in vala) using dbus-daemon. It works fine. But it fails to communicate after dbus-daemon is restarted.
My application ( which is not restarted) tries to re connect to the dbus daemon after dbus daemon is restarted. I have cleanup code for the dbus connection references within my application area. But the GTK.Application initiates dbus connection for its use. This is not cleaned up after dbus daemon is terminated.
Since the references of dbus-connection is not cleaned in the GTK.Application, the dbus-connection returned after failover remains the same and it returns "connection is closed" error for dbus operations.
Is there a way to do a cleanup ( basically remove the references of dbus-connection) in the GTK.Application code?
Or anybody has tried to exclude the dbus-connection initiation in the GTK.Application code during startup?
During my debugging, I tried the following.
I tried to unref the dbus-connection 4-5 times ( within my dbus cleanup code), and then the reconnection to the dbus-daemon would work. This means the dbus-connection is in use in some other area (I assume, GTK.Application code) and it is not properly cleaned up after the dbus-daemon is terminated. When I do unref ( for debugging purpose) 4-5 times in the cleanup code, and then if I stop my application, it results in segmentation fault in the GTK.Application code area ( which is explainable as the stale memory pointers of dbus-connection is still in use in GTK.Application code.

Haven't received any response on this. Any suggestions on where to get some support on this??

It probably is possible to handle a restart of the D-Bus broker/daemon gracefully. It also seems quite hard and nobody does it, so you will encounter difficulties.
Systemd handles a restart of the bus, but it uses sd-bus instead of GDBus.
What you probably need to do, is everybody unrefing the GDBusConnection and invalidating all state from the previous D-Bus session. If you use the singleton from g_bus_get(), ensure that all users also unref it. You might use a library that also uses g_bus_get(), so they need to give up the reference too (and probably those libraries also must sensibly handle the restart). If you use your own GDBusConnection instance (instead of the one from g_bus_get()), it might be simpler. Then poll to reconnect to the bus.

But maybe just don't.
D-Bus provides you with benefits, like defined message ordering and reliable transport. If you assume that your D-Bus connection gets broken (because the daemon restarts) and add code to handle that, it adds a lot of complexity on your side.
It also requires you to add non-trivial code for things that usually don't happen and are probably not well tested.
Instead. Do nothing. Whoever restarts the D-Bus daemon, should also restart your application. In fact, most D-Bus services also don't handle restart well, so those services also need to be restarted. At that point, they might just as well reboot the machine.
There is also little reason to restart the D-Bus daemon, except to see that various things get broken. Just don't do it, or if you do, reboot the machine.
If anything, then dbus-broker/dbus-daemon should implement seamless restart, so that not all clients need to re-implement this. But nobody implements that, so it apparently is not as important as some people think (https://github.com/bus1/dbus-broker/issues/93). Work in this area would benefit everybody, contrary to every D-Bus client trying to handle this on their own.

Thanks for the reply. GLib Application part uses the dbus connection which is what needs to be cleanedup after a restart of dbus-daemon. Is there any way to handle that?

Regarding that, I said "What you probably need to do...". Could you clarify what is unclear about that? Every part of you program (including libraries you use) needs to recognize that the D-Bus connection is broken, give up on their GDBusConnection, properly handle the state that is now invalidated, and recover. What that means in detail, depends what the various parts of your application do.
